# Way to copy row content to different table without having to type all the columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with some columns. For archive purposes I usually create second table that looks exactly the same but I add additional `Primary Key` and `Username/DateTime`. After every edit I call procedure that looks more or less like that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sto_archiwizujPodmiot]
    @varPodmiotID INT, @varUzytkownik NVARCHAR(50), @varUzytkownikData DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PodmiotyHistoria]
           ([PodmiotID]
           ,[PodmiotOsobaNazwisko]
           ,[PodmiotOsobaImie]
           ,[PodmiotUzytkownik]
           ,[PodmiotUzytkownikData])
 SELECT [PodmiotID]
      ,[PodmiotOsobaNazwisko]
      ,[PodmiotOsobaImie]
      ,@varUzytkownik
      ,@varUzytkownikData
  FROM [dbo].[Podmioty]
WHERE [PodmiotID] = @varPodmiotID
END
```

I create such procedure for every single table that I need to have archive for. For example if someone is going to edit some fields before the update happens I call this procedure. Problem is it's a bit of work to create this for every single table, not much but still. Is there a way to make more generalized procedure that would let me do the same but I could call it for every single table just by giving parameters like `TableName`, `ArchiveTableName`, `Username`, `DateTime` or it's what I am supposed to do every time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auditing tables in this way is best done with [triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).

You still need to create a trigger for each such table.

I have found the [following article](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1770) that has scripts that will auto generate the trigger code for the supplied table/s.

Comment: Can I pass values to triggers from c#? Username and DateTime are comming from C# program.

Comment: @MadBoy - You can't supply additional parameters to a trigger. For current `DateTime` you can use the SQL `GETDATE()` function.

Comment: Then i need to continue using stored procedures as I need the username from my program. Program needs to know who made a change.

Comment: @MadBoy - look like you do. You can try to generate your stored procedures using a the approach in the article to generate them instead of triggers.